# Обновить данные в Entity

Tags: php, symfony2, doctrine

Никак не могу нормально обновить данные в Entity: Затирает поле `items`.

Вот Entity:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

/**
 * Class Receipt
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ReceiptRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="receipt")
 *
 * @package AppBundle\Entity
 */
class Receipt
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="shop", type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    private $shop;

    /**
     * @var File
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\File", fetch="EAGER")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="photo_id", nullable=true, onDelete="SET NULL")
     */
    private $photoId;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $date;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime")
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="amount", type="string")
     */
    private $amount;

    /**
     * @var ListItem
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\ListItem", mappedBy="receipt")
     */
    private $items;

    /**
     * @var User
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User", fetch="EAGER")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_holder", onDelete="SET NULL")
     */
     private $user;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->items = new ArrayCollection();
    }
    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $id
     */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getShop()
    {
        return $this->shop;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $shop
     */
    public function setShop($shop)
    {
        $this->shop = $shop;
    }

    /**
     * @return File
     */
    public function getPhotoId()
    {
        return $this->photoId;
    }

    /**
     * @param File $photoId
     */
    public function setPhotoId($photoId)
    {
        $this->photoId = $photoId;
    }

    /**
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getDate()
    {
        return $this->date;
    }

    /**
     * @param \DateTime $date
     */
    public function setDate($date)
    {
        $this->date = $date;
    }

    /**
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getCreatedAt()
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    /**
     * @param \DateTime $createdAt
     */
    public function setCreatedAt($createdAt)
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAmount()
    {
        return $this->amount;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $amount
     */
    public function setAmount($amount)
    {
        $this->amount = $amount;
    }

    /**
     * @param ListItem $item
     */
    public function addItems(ListItem $item)
    {
        $this->items->add($item);
    }

    /**
     * @param ListItem $item
     */
    public function removeItems(ListItem $item)
    {
        $this->items->remove($item);
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getItems()
    {
       return $this->items;
    }
    /**
     * @return User
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    /**
     * @param User $user
     */
    public function setUser($user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }


}
```

а вот, собственно, и способ Добавить или Обновить данные:

```
 public function fillReceipt(User $user,ParamFetcherInterface $fetcher,$listsItems,Receipt $receipt = null)
{
    if($receipt == null) {
        $receipt = new Receipt();
    }

    if($fetcher->get('amount') !== null){
        $receipt->setAmount($fetcher->get('amount'));
    }elseif($receipt->getAmount() !== null){
        $receipt->setAmount($receipt->getAmount());
    }else{
        $receipt->setAmount(null);
    }

    if($fetcher->get('date') !== null){
        $receipt->setDate(new \DateTime($fetcher->get('date'), $a = new \DateTimeZone('GMT')));
    }elseif($receipt->getDate() !== null){
        $receipt->setDate($receipt->getDate());
    }else{
        $receipt->setDate(null);
    }

    if($fetcher->get('shopName') !== null){
        $receipt->setShop($fetcher->get('shopName'));
    }elseif($receipt->getShop() !== null){
        $receipt->setShop($receipt->getShop());
    }else{
        $receipt->setShop(null);
    }

    $flag = 0;
    foreach($listsItems as $item)
    {
        if($item !== null){
            $flag = 1;
        }
    }

    if($flag == 1) {
        $receipt = $this->fillReceiptItems($receipt, $listsItems);
    }

    $receipt->setUser($user);
    $receipt->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime('now', new \DateTimeZone('GMT')));

    $this->_em->persist($receipt);
    $this->_em->flush();

    return $receipt->getId();
}
```

На обновление из контроллера вызываю так:

```
 /**
 * Update receipt
 * ("X-Auth-Token", "id" - are required parameters)
 *
 * @Route("/receipt/{id}", methods={"PUT"})
 * @ApiDoc(
 *     resource=true,
 *     section="Receipt"
 * )
 * @RequestParam(name="amount",nullable=true)
 * @RequestParam(name="shopName",nullable=true)
 * @RequestParam(name="date", description="YYYY-mm-dd",nullable=true)
 * @RequestParam(name="notes",nullable=true)
 * @RequestParam(name="items",array=true,nullable=true)
 *
 * @return Receipt
 */
public function putUpdateReceiptAction($id,Request $request, ParamFetcherInterface $fetcher)
{
    try {
        $apiKey = $request->headers->get('X-Auth-Token');
        $token = $this->get('app.repository.api_token')->findNotExpiredApiTokenByApiKey($apiKey);
        /** @var User $user */
        $user = $this->get('app.repository.user')->find($token->getUser()->getId());
        $items[] = null;
        $k = 0;
        foreach($fetcher->get('items') as $ids) {
            $items[$k] = $this->get('app.repository.listitem')->find($ids);
            $k++;
        }
        $receipt = $this->get('app.repository.receipt')->find($id);
        $this->get('app.repository.receipt')->fillReceipt($user,$fetcher,$items,$receipt);
        return $this->get('app.repository.receipt')->find($id);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return $this->get('app.service.response')->ExceptionHandler($e);
    } catch (BadRequestHttpException $e) {
        return $this->get('app.service.response')->BadRequestHttpExceptionHandler($e);
    }
}
```

но при обновлении `items` - пустые, даже если я их передаю методом `PUT`.

Comment: метод 
` /**
     * @param Receipt $receipt
     * @param $lists
     * @return Receipt
     */
    private function fillReceiptItems(Receipt $receipt, $lists)
    {
        /** @var ListItem $listItem */
        foreach($lists as $listItem) {
            if ($listItem !== null && $listItem->getChecked() == 1) {
                $receipt->addItems($listItem);
            }
        }
        return $receipt;
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обратите внимание на данный класс, который реализует связь "один ко многим"

```
<?php
namespace Test\TestBundle\Entity;

use Tpg\ExtjsBundle\Annotation as Extjs;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as JMS;
use \Test\TestBundle\Entity\Car;

/**
 * @Extjs\Model
 * @Extjs\ModelProxy("/mycarowners")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="car_owner")
 */
class CarOwner {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @JMS\Type("integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Test\TestBundle\Entity\Car", mappedBy="carOwner")
     * @JMS\Type("ArrayCollection<Test\TestBundle\Entity\Car>")
     */
    protected $cars;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->cars = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Add cars
     *
     * @param Car $cars
     * @return CarOwner
     */
    public function addCar(Car $cars)
    {
        $this->cars[] = $cars;
        $cars->setCarOwner($this);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove cars
     *
     * @param Car $cars
     */
    public function removeCar(Car $car)
    {
        $this->cars->removeElement($car);
        $cars->setCarOwner(null);
    }

    /**
     * Get cars
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getCars()
    {
        return $this->cars;
    }
```

}

[источник](https://github.com/AmsTaFFix/extjs-bundle/blob/master/Tests/Fixtures/Test/TestBundle/Entity/CarOwner.php)